# How to optimize qt tablewidget refreshing?

Tags: algorithm, qt, user-interface, optimization

I'am using qt to develop a monitor which shows new log items received from the network.
I use **QTableWidget** to display the **dynamic items received** and the table only shows 100 rows.
The problem is: the monitor will receive some 400 'messages' per sec and update the rows.
I found using **setItem(row,col,item)** and **new QTableWidgetItem()** is quite time-consuming, I only want to show the newest items(three strings at 3 cols) from top to buttom.
But the method is really time-consuming, it costs 5.281s when I add 4000 test cases at one time, which should finish in 4000/400 = 10s.
***So it costs the half time, how to shorten the time? Any better methods to use the qt tablewidget?***  ;) Thanks for reading!

The filterLog function code:

```
    start = clock();
    filter_log_display();
    duration_filterLogDisplay += (double)(finish - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

filter_log_display():

```
    clock_t start = clock();
    row_selectable = false;
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(0);//delete table items all
    row_selectable = true;

    int size_1 = logDisplayQueue.size() - 1;

    ui->tableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->setSliderPosition(0);

    if(size_1+1 < 100)
    {
        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(size_1 + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(100);
    }
    clock_t finish = clock();
    duration_setRowCount += (double)(finish - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    for(int queue_i = size_1, index = 0; queue_i >= 0; queue_i--, index++)
    {
        start = clock();
        LogInfoItem* logItem = (LogInfoItem*)logDisplayQueue.at(queue_i);
        finish = clock();
        duration_getItemFQueue += (double)(finish - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        start = clock();
        QString BITS_str = bits2Hexs(logItem->BITS);
        finish = clock();
        duration_bits2Hexs += (double)(finish - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        start = clock();
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(index, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(logItem->time));//time
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(index, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(logItem->name));//name
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(index, 2, new QTableWidgetItem(BITS_str));//BITS
        finish = clock();
        duration_setItem += (double)(finish - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        start = clock();
        if(queue_i == oldRowItemNo)ui->tableWidget->selectRow(index);
        finish = clock();
        duration_ifSelectRow += (double)(finish - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    }
```

Analysis about time: :) There are many places to optimize including this one :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that each call of `QTableWidget->setItem` triggers a paint event. You can try to disable UI updates while inside function `filter_log_display()` as explained for
[a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770084/efficiently-updating-a-qtableview-at-high-speed).

Or you replace QTableWidget by a QTableView and [implement a table model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#creating-new-models) around your queue.

Comment: Tank you!!! The way is so elegant, I've tried another way to avoid calling the function but updating data elsewhere. Thank you after all!!!